# Finding Confusion Matrix from TPR and FPR

Tags: roc, confusion-matrix

The confusion matrix is made up of `TN`, `FN`, `FP`, `TP`. Given the True Postive Rate `TPR` and the True Negative Rate `FPR`, is it possible to derive the confusion matrix?

Will knowing the Observed Positive `OP` and Observed Negative `ON` help? I'm using the `sklearn` package from Python to assit me in creating this confusion matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Observe:
$$TPR=\frac{TP}{TP+FN}$$
$$FPR=\frac{FP}{FP+TN}$$
and 
$$
OP=FN+TP
$$
$$
ON=TN+FP.
$$

This is four equations with four unknowns, so it can be solved with some algebra.